# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Session Is Recreated After Any Changes Source Code

Tags: session, asp.net-core

I use sessions in my ASP.NET Core application.

My **ConfigureServices** in **Startup.cs** looks like this

```
Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(Options =>
{                
    Options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    Options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
}); 
Services.AddSession(Options =>
{
    Options.Cookie.Name = ".MySessionName";
    Options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;                
});
```

Here is the problem I have: I open my website in browser and set some value to session. I navigate on pages and value I set to session is there. All Good.

Without closing browser or leaving a page, I go back to Visual Studio, make changes to my code, save it, come back to browser, reload page and all my session values are gone.

How can I fix this?

Sample project: https://bitbucket.org/63bits/netcoresessionissue/src/master/

Comment: I don't think its possible to maintain a session even browser is closed, but you have to rethink your requirement and you can save data in cookies which will persist till the expire time.

Comment: I think i wasn't clear, that I'm not closing a browser or leaving a page. Both browser and page stay open. All I do is make changes in code and reload a page. (I made an edit in my post, to make it more clear). BTW there is no problem like this in regular ASP.NET MVC Application.

Comment: Don't you stop the running project to change code and rerun the project?Is it possible that your session has expired?

Comment: I run them in ctrl+F5 mode, rather then just F5. 100% sure that sessioni is not expiring. It can't expire in 5 seconds and only in case when I make changes and save, which actually causes project recompilation in .net core

Comment: I've also included a sample project where issue is described

Comment: I understand what your are describing but IMO,it is a normal behavior since session is kept on server side instead of client side.You have to go to page where reset the session.Maybe you  could refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708120/asp-mvc-is-session-lost-upon-building-solution